# WDM Build with no INF?

Tags: c++, driver, visual-studio-2013

I am trying to build a non pnp driver (WDM) for Windows XP Service Pack 3. I am using Visual Studio 2013 and WDK 8.1. The code is very simple and straight forward (just for testing on a VM). The only problem i have is the following:

**"Inf2Cat, signability test failed."**

Here code snippet:

```
#include "DHSD.h"
#define _DRIVER_NAME_ "DHSD"

NTSTATUS DriverEntry(_In_ PDRIVER_OBJECT driverObject, _In_ PUNICODE_STRING regPath)
{
    UNREFERENCED_PARAMETER(regPath);
    driverObject->DriverUnload = DriverUnload;

    DbgPrint("Driver loaded.");

    return STATUS_SUCCESS;
}

VOID DriverUnload(_In_ PDRIVER_OBJECT driverObject)
{
    UNREFERENCED_PARAMETER(driverObject);
    DbgPrint("Driver unloaded.");
    return;
}
```

The thing is i dont want to sign my driver, neither i want to distribute it, so is there any workaround for this? Thanks

Answer (score 0):

you are missing the KMDF 1.11 coinstaller DLL in your package.

I made similar program and it works perfectly fine

```
#include "ntddk.h"

#include "stdio.h"

#include "stdlib.h"

void DriverUnload( 

PDRIVER_OBJECT pDriverObject) 

{  

DbgPrint("Driver unloading\n"); 
}

NTSTATUS DriverEntry( 

PDRIVER_OBJECT DriverObject, 

PUNICODE_STRING RegistryPath) 

{ 
PDEVICE_OBJECT pdo;

DriverObject->DriverUnload = DriverUnload; 

    DbgPrint("Hello, World\n"); 

return STATUS_SUCCESS; 
}
```

also could check the cat file for any 64 bit decoration error

Comment: I am using WDM driver not KMDF does the coinstaller still works?

Answer (score 0):

You can delete the package project from your solution and it should work afterwards. This is the quickest "hacky" solution.